# "and" condition in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

> +++ this is a random text ...

How do I achieve that BOTH the plus chars + backspace at the beginning and the dot chars at the end + backspace get removed, leaving the following string:

> this is a random text

I have come up with the following regex:

```
(^(+{3}\s))(\s[.]{3}$)
```

How do I need to adapt the regex?

Comment: I think the easiest one is `[\w\s]+`

Comment: `str.match(/\w+/g).join(' ')`. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5eaecsqf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `/(?:^\+*\s*|\s*\.*$)/g`

In JavaScript:

```
"+++ this is a random text ...".replace(/(?:^\+*\s*|\s*\.*$)/g, "")
```

Explanation:

- `^\+*\s*`: zero or more pluses at the beginning of the string with optional trailing whitespace
- `\s*\.*$`: zero or more dots at the end of the string with optional leading whitespace

---

That said, it's probably a lot more readable to write `trimStart` and `trimEnd` functions that remove the `+` and `.` characters:

```
"+++ this is a random text ...".trimStart("+").trimEnd(".").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` to replace a matching regular expression in this case `[+.]`  notice we need to escape the `.` > `[+\.]` and we also have to apply it globally `g` resulting to `/[+\.]/g`

```
var str = "+++ this is a random ++text ..."

str.replace(/[+\.]/g, '')
```

to remove white spaces at the end and beginning of our string, we can apply the `.trim()` method

```
str.replace(/[+\.]/g, '').trim()
```